# Pentest scenario where ping multiple Hosts is useful?

Tags: penetration-test

I would like to know if there's any pentesting scenarios where ping multiple hosts is useful for the pentester.

EDIT. Of course any other that know if the host is live...

Comment: If you don't know the network at all it can be useful to ping the whole network to map it. Also if you want to fingerprint those hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Pinging during pentesting is only helpful for a quick determination of what is ***immediately*** reachable. Nothing more, and nothing less. It should ***not be*** used for complete discovery of what is, or isn't on a network since some hosts (even on an internal scan (ping sweep)) may not return an ICMP response. During pentesting, I rely on networking knowledge, e.g. ARP, network ranges, moreso than ping.